# Xamarin Android build fails in AppCenter (Azure) with Error APT0000

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-app-center

Xamarin Android project is built well locally on Windows/Mac, but fails on AppCenter/Azure pipelines with weird errors like:

*Error APT0000: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.companyname.build_testing_andx:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.*

*Error APT0000: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.companyname.build_testing_andx:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.*

This mostly looks like lack of necessary libraries to restore by Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

*As it appeared after long investigation, and no matter how the solution sounds dumb, but the solution might save some time for someone.*

The reason such projects can't be build on AppCenter/Azure (and that ***might be related to any other Visual Studio project***) is that *Nuget packages not being restored successfully*.
The problem is that when using Nuget task, it doesn't indicate any issues. It just finishes well.

But it happens **because the sources don't include *.sln file**, thus Nuget doesn't have a point where to start from for the packages restoring.
Sometimes it might happen when this file is just not included into sources pushed to repository by number of reasons.

*(It's weird because the builds often project-oriented, and when working on Visual Studio it automatically creates the *.sln file (not necessary around the project folder), so sometimes it might just be not included and you have no idea what's causing the errors above).*

So, just to be sure you've got your *.sln file added to your repository and it's available for the AppCenter/Azure build.

Comment: Yeah but what's the solution?

Comment: Thanks for pointing. I thought it's clear from the issue cause description, but I will update the answer. :)